# Toastr not working as intended? Showing up at bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, toastr

This is what I have written for my toastr.

```
toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": true,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": true,
        "progressBar": false,
        "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
        "preventDuplicates": false,
        "onclick": null,
        "showDuration": "300",
        "hideDuration": "1000",
        "timeOut": "5000",
        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    };

    toastr.error(message, 'Error');
```

This is what it looks like. What am I doing wrong? The red is the toastr (note: at the bottom of the screen).

[image]

Comment: Update post with what styles you are applying on toastr elements

Comment: I don't have any.

Comment: How is your js and jquery applied? And what version of jquery you using?

Comment: after realising I didn't have any styles applied, I added the correct .css file to the project and now it seems to be working correctly. Thanks for putting me on the right track!